# Django - 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'headers'

Tags: python, django, attributes

I am getting this error on django with my dict and OrderedDict (doesnt matter which one I use).
I am trying to submit a CHECKSUM do paygate which I am generating with my md5 hash using the data dict. The response I get back from paygate is the PAY_REQUEST_ID and the CHECKSUM which is regenerated with dict_ in my post_payment method. I am getting the correct response as I can see my PAY_REQUEST_ID and new CHECKSUM but for some reason the 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'headers' error pops up and I have not used 'headers' anywhere in my code.

Can someone help in identifying what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

```
#just for reference i am putting 2 items in dict
response_data = OrderedDict()
data = {
        'PAYGATE_ID'    : '10011072130',
        'REFERENCE'     : 'pgtest_123456789',
       } 
CHECKSUM = calculate_md5(data)
url = 'https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans'
data['CHECKSUM'] =  CHECKSUM
data['url'] = url
hash_valid, response_data = post_payment(data)
if not hash_valid:
    return HttpResponseForbidden('FAILED')
response_data.pop('PAYGATE_ID')
response_data.pop('REFERENCE')
return response_data


def post_payment(data):
   url = data.pop('url')
   response = requests.post(url,data=data)
   dict_ = OrderedDict()
   new = response.text.split('&')
   print(new)
   for item in new:
       list_ = item.split('=')
       key = list_[0]
       value = list_[1]
       dict_[key] = value
   is_equal, dict_['CHECKSUM'] = validate_checksum(dict_)
   return is_equal, dict_

def validate_checksum(data):
   hash_ = data.pop('CHECKSUM')
   new_hash = calculate_md5(data)
   return hash_ == new_hash, new_hash
```

Full Traceback

**response = get_response(request)**

AttributeError("'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'headers'")
get_response
<django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware object at 0x0000016523EDFF28>
request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/carts/checkout/'>

**response = self.process_response(request, response)**

request
<WSGIRequest: GET '/carts/checkout/'>
response
OrderedDict([('PAY_REQUEST_ID', '9D29D540-FED8-9693-FEA1-2D6B64A5868E'),
('CHECKSUM', '097e4a83deb5f5c3840ea3e2b69e422e')])
self
<django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware object at 0x0000026DCA93FEB8>

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback.

Comment: we need more information about the error. I think that can be the Clickjacking Protection Middleware. What kind of interaction do you do with the payment system ?

Comment: Is `response_data` a dictionary? You write `return response_data` is that in a _view_? A view should return an `HttpResponse` (or something inheriting from it) object and not something else. Also please see how to write a [mre] (one of the parts of which is _completeness_, i.e. your example should be complete and can be run by itself).

Comment: response_data = OrderedDict() I need to submit the response data in a form to paygate

Comment: Removed return resonse_data and solved that error. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Removed 'return resonse_data' and solved that error.

```
CHECKSUM = calculate_md5(data)
url = 'https://secure.paygate.co.za/payweb3/initiate.trans'
data['CHECKSUM'] =  CHECKSUM
data['url'] = url
hash_valid, response_data = post_payment(data)
if not hash_valid:
    return HttpResponseForbidden('FAILED')
response_data.pop('PAYGATE_ID')
response_data.pop('REFERENCE')
```